# Error in Raster/Merge tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, gdal-merge

I am completely new to QGIS. I am on a Mac using OS 10.13.6. I have installed QGIS 3.6, and installed Python 3.6.8 per install instructions. I opened a terminal window to check python install:

```
EricsMacBookPro:~ ericfoertsch$ python
Python 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:04:31)
```

So I think I am good and on with the show.

I have 10 files I am trying to merge using Raster/Merge tool.

1. When I enter the file names in Raster/Merge dialog box I get this error:

   > 'Incorrect parameter value for INPUT' .
2. If I click on Run as Batch Process and enter same values I get this error message:

   > 'Wrong or missing parameter value:Input values(row 1)'.
3. I put double quotes around the file name strings in both input layers and merged file name and clicked Run again. This time I got logged output but with an error:

   > GDAL command:
   >   gdal_merge.py -ot Float32 -of -o "\"/Users/ericfoertsch/Google 
   >   Drive/Documents/Condor Scenary V2/New England/Merged Bil file/NewEngland.bil\"" --optfile 
   >   /var/folders/sy/mbkmjwg12lb1df08dgjw7psh0000gp/T/processing_7e37da37ef8f4cfd89156358b42637eb/fa859f8db49c4623b356e04a58da9fdb/mergeInputFiles.txt
   >   GDAL command output:
   >   /bin/sh: gdal_merge.py: command not found
4. I opened a terminal window and typed in gdal_merge.py and it executed so I am not sure why it shows gdal_merge.py not found:

   > EricsMacBookPro:~ ericfoertsch$ gdal_merge.py
   >   No input files selected.
   >   Usage: gdal_merge.py [-o out_filename] [-of out_format] [-co NAME=VALUE]*
   >                    [-ps pixelsize_x pixelsize_y] [-tap] [-separate] [-q] [-v] [-pct]
   >                    [-ul_lr ulx uly lrx lry] [-init "value [value...]"]
   >                    [-n nodata_value] [-a_nodata output_nodata_value]
   >                    [-ot datatype] [-createonly] input_files
   >                    [--help-general]
5. Continuing the saga, I cut pasted the batch command into the terminal window:

   > gdal_merge.py -ot Float32 -of EHdr -o "/Users/ericfoertsch/Google Drive/Documents/Condor Scenary V2/New England/Merged Bil file/NewEngland.bil" --optfile /var/folders/sy/mbkmjwg12lb1df08dgjw7psh0000gp/T/processing_7e37da37ef8f4cfd89156358b42637eb/58cfba9edf9f435cb75ca505c11d85ae/mergeInputFiles.txt

   And got an error msg:

   > No input files selected.
6. So I checked the ..../mergeInputFiles.txt file and it was empty. I guess I expected to see the 10 file names I had entered.
7. So I entered the 10 file names (I am really desperate by now) and tried running the `gdal_merge` command in the terminal window and got a series of error messages similar to:

   > ERROR 4: `/Users/ericfoertsch/NewEngland/USGSBilFiles/n42_w074_1arc_v3.bil' not recognized as a supported file format.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the `.bil` file format, so I looked into whether QGIS supports it, and found [this tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/open_bil_bip_bsq_files.html). Apparently you need to create support files.

Comment: I'm not sure but try running the command from another directory without the spaces in the name. I've already hit my head a lot because of the spaces in the folder names.

Comment: csk - I had moved the .bil files without the corresponding .hdr files, so I thought that might be my problem, so tried again with the .hdr present in same directory, but again no luck. So I deleted the QGIS 3.6 version and installed an older QGIS 2.18.0 version. That seems to be working, so I am going to forge on ahead with output from that version. I am keeping my fingers crossed all will be OK.